# Adding Bootstrap 4 modal in Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-modal, webpack-2, bootstrap-4

I wanted to use only bootstrap modal functionality, so i've manually added those libs (modal.js & util.js) to vendor in webpack.config.js

But if i directly add the vendor.js it works. Since it is bundle i don't want to refer directly instead i need to map the vendor bundle though system.config.js

How can i achieve it ? please suggest

**My webpack.config.js**

```js
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'

export default [{
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
      vendor: ['jquery', '/node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/util', '/node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/modal'],
      main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibssrc/shared/js/main'),
      globalNavigation: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibssrc/modules/global-navigation/js/index'),
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibsdist/js-bundle'),
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
    target: 'web',
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        comments: false
      })
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.es6', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      }, {
        test: /\.es6$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }, {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
      'external-global-navigation': [path.resolve(__dirname, 'ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibssrc/modules/global-navigation/js/index')]
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibsdist/js-bundle'),
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
    target: 'web',
    externals: {
      'jquery': 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'external-global-navigation'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        comments: false
      })
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.es6', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      }, {
        test: /\.es6$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }, {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }]
    }
  }
]
```

**My System.config.js**

```js
System.config({
  baseURL: '/',
  transpiler: 'ts',
  meta: {
    typescript: {
      exports: 'ts'
    }
  },
  map: {
    jquery: '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    ts: '/node_modules/plugin-typescript/lib/plugin.js',
    typescript: '/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
  },
  packages: {
    'static/clientlibs/src/shared/js': {
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    'static/clientlibs/src/modules/': {
      defaultExtension: 'ts',
      meta: {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
System.import('/static/clientlibs/src/shared/js/main');
```

**My HTML**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So What i've done is,

1. Changed Bootstrap modal reference from `js/dist/modal` to `js/src/modal`
2. In system config, i've add the modal reference
3. Import modal in main.ts
4. Add alias in webpack

By doing so we can use only bootstrap modal functionality. Hope it helps

**System.config.js**

```js
map: {
  jquery: '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  ts: '/node_modules/plugin-typescript/lib/plugin.js',
  typescript: '/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
  modal: '/node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/modal.js'
}
```

**main.ts**

```js
import 'modal';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
//Update Vendor
vendor: ['jquery', 'modal'],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.es6', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      modal: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/modal'),
    }
  },
```